# rails jumbotron dynamic background image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to display my model's image inside a jumbotron. Something like this:

```
<div class="jumbotron" style="background-image: url(http://www.californiafootgolfclub.com/static/img/footgolf-1.jpg);">
   <div class="container for-about">
   <h1>About</h1>
   </div>
</div>
```

but I want the image to be dynamic:

```
<%=image_tag @group.group_avatar.url(:original) %>
```

How do I achieve this? Seems simple and there seem to be a lot of questions on this topic and not finding for my specific use case.

Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

The code is just like:

```
<div class="jumbotron" style="background-image: url(<%= @group.group_avatar.url(:original) %>);background-repeat:no-repeat;">
   <div class="container for-about">
   <h1>About</h1>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is causing the image to repeat 4 times across the page - http://imgur.com/NNJp5Xu.

Comment: Try to add `background-repeat:no-repeat;`, check it out please

Answer (score 0):

use it

```
<div class="jumbotron" style="background-image: url(<%= @group.group_avatar.url(:original) %>);background-repeat:no-repeat!important;">
   <div class="container for-about">
   <h1>About</h1>
   </div>
</div>
```